# NET Maui: Cannot Publish with Visual Studio 2022 Apps for Android 10

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui

When I try to publish I cannot do it in Android 11, because I cannot select target Android 10. I have installed sdk platform 30. When I publish I get a app that does not work with Android 10. Thank you very much

SDK INSTALLED:

[image]

TARGET VERSION:

[image]

I tried to install, unistall and reinstall sdk, but never appears like a target version

Comment: You should always target the highest version. Why are you specifically trying to target Android 10? You won't be able to publish that on Googe Play. Read this: https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk

Comment: I won't to publish on Google Play. It's only for me and I have a Android 10 Phone and I would like to use the app in my phone, but when I publish and install in my phone I cannot use. It's say me that it's not a correct application. In adittion, I don't understand if you publish in Google Play and your future clients have not Android 12 how can they use your application? Thank you very much

Comment: Did you read the article? You can still install apps that target a higher version on devices running a lower version. That's why you can also set a minimum SDK version. However, it's your responsibility as a developer to ensure that only APIs are used that are available on a specific platform. When you install an app with a higher target SDK on a device with a lower version, you won't be able to use certain APIs. You can check the device's Android version at runtime for this. Try setting the target SDK and the API version (two settings in your project file) to the highest one available.

Comment: Yes, I did. Perhaps, the minimun version I put (API 29), and the version that my phone use (API 30) haven't elements that only can be use with upper version of API. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From document [Understanding Android API levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=windows), we know that:

> Beginning in August 2021, the Google Play Console requires that new
> apps target API level 30 (Android 11.0) or higher. Existing apps are
> required to target API level 30 or higher beginning in November 2021.
> For more information, see Target API level requirements for the Play
> Console in "Create and set up your app" in the Play Console
> documentation.

So, you can try to set the target API  to level 30 (Android 11.0) or higher.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't appear in Target Android Version. Only appear Android 13.0,12.1 and 12.0. I tried to include, addind the SDK, but It doesn`t appear. If you know how to do it, please tell me. Thank you

Comment: You can try to repair your visual studio or install the latest version of visual studio.

Comment: I have the last one. Version 17.4.2. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to repair your visual studio?

Comment: It scares me because I have other applications developed with this version and I don't want it to break because those others are important. Perhaps it would be interesting to set up a virtual machine with visual studio and do the tests there. Thank you very much